# Have to kill pdf reader process to see edits in pdf file

Tags: windows-8, pdf-reader

I make a pdf file via MikTeX, and open it with the built-in Windows 8 pdf reader. I then close the reader. I edit my source, recompile, and open the new pdf. What I see does not have the edits. I close the reader.

Now I go into the task manager and I see that the reader process is still running. I kill the process, recompile my source and open the pdf. Now I see the edits. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is just a really bad design choice by Microsoft.

The PDF reader, being an "app", doesn't actually close when you click the X in the top right corner. This wouldn't be a problem, except that it doesn't detect changes to the currently rendered file, so when I modify the PDF via TeX, the PDF reader maintains the original version even after "closing" it.

You *can* actually close the reader by dragging the window to the bottom of the screen and waiting a few seconds.